# How to use any variable in other member functions in c++

Tags: c++, oop

```
class screen
{
public:  screen(vector<int>v)
    {
        vector<vector<int>>seats(v[0]+1,vector<int>(v[1]+1,1));
       // done some operations on v
  
    }
    
bool check_seat(vector<int>v)
    {
        int row=v[0];
   // I want to use seats vector in this function too. How to do that??
        for(int i=1;i<v.size();i++)
        {
            if(abs(seats[row][v[i]])==2){return false;}
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to use seats vector in check seat function too. I have declared it in the constructor.
Also, can we declare a variable (seats) outside the constructor and then define its size in the constructor itself using the data we have inside v.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to make "seats" a member of "screen".  So you initialize it in your constructor, but you can also use it in member function "check_seat()".  Right?  Just move the "seats" declaration *before* the constructor (making it a "class member").  I'd make it "private", unless you had a compelling need to do otherwise.

Comment: @paulsm4 yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `seats` is a *local variable* in the constructor.  You need to make it a *class member* instead:

```
class screen
{
public:
    screen(const vector<int>& v)
        : seats(v[0]+1, vector<int>(v[1]+1, 1))
    {
    }

    // etc...

private:
    vector<vector<int>> seats;
};
```

Note that I also changed your constructor to accept the vector as a *const reference*.  There seemed to be no reason why it should be passed *by value*.

Comment: Bro your code worked but I am not sure how. Can you please suggest some reference for it idk what we call this technique? I want to read more about it. It would be really helpful , thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members

Answer (score 1):

You've a couple of options.

1. Declare your vector of vectors (like  a 2-d matrix) as a member variable of the screen class. In C++ (and also in Java) when you declare something (an object, struct, another class, or a data structure) as a member of a class, you're free to perform any operations on that member variable inside that class.

```
class MyClass {
private:
  int numSeats;
  int* numArray;
public:
  int getNumSeats() {
    return numSeats;
  }

  bool allSeatsFull() {
    for (int i=0;i<numSeats;++i) {
       if (numArray[i] == 0) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
  ...
};
```

When declared this way numArray can be operated on inside functions that are part of MyClass. Of course, whenever you add a member variable to a class or a struct it increases the size of the object of that class - which is almost always proportional to the sum of the sizes of the members of that class or struct. (I say almost always because some times alignment of addresses comes into the picture which you're encouraged you to look into).

2. Create a function screen::getSeats() which returns the seats 2-d vector as like a one time thing. For e.g., you may do this when you need the seats 2-d vector only once in checkSeats function.

Using 1 over 2 or otherwise is implementation/use dependent.

Comment: can i declare my vector as a member variable of screen class and define its size in the constructor?

Comment: yeah. if the size of your vector (V) is known beforehand then either use the constructor initializer list syntax or call V.resize in the body of the ctor to create space for N items of size N*sizeof(T) where T is the type elements contained in your vector (std::vector<T>).